# How to properly delete 1+ object from vector of uniq_ptr's

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have:

```
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Zombie>> zombie;
        for(unsigned j=0; j < zombie.size(); j++)
        {    
              if(bullet intersects zombie)
              {             
                  zombie.erase(zombie.begin()+j)
              }
        }
```

I would like to delete specific object/s in vector of unique pointers. Above example works, but my lecturer said that this way doesn't guarantee that all proper objects will be deleted. I have spent  long time to figure it out somehow, but I don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: Use the remove-erase idiom.

Comment: Do you understand *why*  your current approach is flawed?

Comment: `zombie.erase(std::remove(...`?

Comment: No, tbh idk why current approach is flawed :(

Comment: What if there are two zombies right next to each other that are to be erased?  Check your logic, especially with `j`.  Or imagine if there are only two zombies in the vector, and both are to be removed.  How will your loop work? (again, check `j`).

Comment: Understanding the problem with the current code is a requirement in order to understand *what* you need to fix. And to understand what is wrong now, think about how both `j` and `zombie` look like after your code execute the `if` branch

Comment: This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with `uniq_ptr`s per se. The overall removal logic is flawed, and has the same problem no matter what's in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lecturer is correct.

Your loop unconditionally increments `j` on every iteration regardless of whether `erase()` is called.  So, whenever you do call `erase()`, the indexes of the remaining elements decrement, but you increment `j` anyway, skipping the *next* element that followed the "erased" element.

One solution is to increment `j` only on iterations that do not call `erase()`, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Zombie>> zombies;
...
for(size_t j = 0; j < zombies.size(); )
{    
    auto &zombie = zombies[j];

    if (bullet intersects zombie)
    {
        zombies.erase(zombies.begin()+j);
    }
    else
    {
        ++j;
    }
}
```

Or, using iterators instead of indexes:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Zombie>> zombies;
...
for(auto iter = zombies.begin(); iter != zombies.end(); )
{    
    auto &zombie = *iter;

    if (bullet intersects zombie)
    {
        iter = zombies.erase(iter);
    }
    else
    {
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

An alternative solution is to use the remove-erase idiom instead, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Zombie>> zombies;
...
zombies.erase(
    std::remove_if(zombies.begin(), zombies.end(),
        [&](std::unique_ptr<Zombie> &zombie) { return (bullet intersects zombie); }
    ),
    zombies.end()
);
```

[`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) will first "remove" all of the matching elements by moving them to the end of the `vector`, returning an iterator to the first "removed" element.  And then passing that range of "removed" elements to [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) will physically remove them from the `vector`.

Alternatively, in C++20 and later, you can use [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) instead, which makes the `remove_if()` and `erase()` calls for you, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Zombie>> zombies;
...
std::erase_if(zombies,
    [&](auto &zombie){ return (bullet intersects zombie); }
);
```